# Leaflet draw - input-based circlemarker radius

Tags: leaflet

I am developing a snazzy drawing kit based on the Leaflet draw plugin. What I would love to have is the input-based circle marker radius. My code looks like this:

```
var layer = e.layer,
  type = e.layerType;
feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
let x = 1
var title = prompt("Please provide the name", "default");
var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefined");
var id = x++;
feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
var PopupOptions = {
  'maxWidth': '400',
  'className': 'PopupDrawMarker'
}
layer.bindPopup('<b>Name: </b>' + title + '<br> <b>Value: </b>' + value)
layer.bindTooltip('<b></b>' + title, {
  permanent: true,
  direction: 'center',
  offset: [0, 1],
  className: 'draw-label',
  noWrap: true
}
)
if (type === 'marker' || type === 'circlemarker') {
  e.layer.options.color = '#170022'
  var jobnumber = prompt("Please provide the number of orders", 0)
  var MarkerPopup = '<b>Your survey: </b> ' + value
  layer.bindPopup(MarkerPopup, PopupOptions).on('click', function (e) {
  });
  layer.bindTooltip('<b></b>' + title, {
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'center',
    offset: [0, -20],
    className: 'draw-label',
    noWrap: true
  }
  )
} else if (type === 'circlemarker') {
  radius: jobnumber
}
```

I have the radius of my `circlemarker` set as 10, which is the default option. After the `jobnumber` input it doesn't change at all. I wish I could have the radius related to the number input. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no circle marker definition in the code above and statement `if (type === 'circlemarker') {radius: jobnumber}` makes no sense.

Comment: I've based it on marker type, which is circlearker. Is there some solution for it at all?

Comment: When I write it make no sense I mean it in JS syntax sense. What is sentence `radius: jobnumber` supposed to do? It's illegal syntax,

Comment: the radius: jobnumber supposed to pick up the input value from var jobnumber = prompt ("Please provide the number of orders",0) if number of orders is 5 then radius should be 5 something like this.

Comment: Again, JS statement `radius: jobnumber` makes no sense. What would make sense: `var someOption = {radius: jobnumber}` or `someOption.radius = jobnumber` or `var radius = jobnumber` and so on.

Comment: var radius = jobnumber doesn't work as well as similar approaches. The problem here is, that the radius is the option for circlemarker and probably doesn't need to be set as a separated variable. This is how I understand it, but I don't know am I right.

Comment: I personally don't understand what you would like to achieve. To specify the circle radius and click on the map and add the circle with specified radius?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have the circle with a radius specified by the number input defined in prompt var jobnumber = prompt("Please provide the number of orders", 0)

Comment: Ok. Where will the circle be located?

Comment: It can be located anywhere after clicking. I am developing the Leaflet draw plugin and in this event, the circlemarker will be used as the new feature.

Comment: can you share head tag part of html. there are different versions of draw plugin. which one do you use. the plugin in leaflet website has no circlemarker i guess.

Comment: in which event are you using this code?

Comment: I use it for Python folium. The full script is based here: https://jsfiddle.net/ryxjveqs/

Comment: The script in  jsfiddle doesn't work on my side.

Comment: It won't work, as I put just the code like I usually do. Is there something, which could be precise enough or would you like to have the entire map prepared in the Python folium library? I attached basically the whole JavaScript code from the %macro% element.

Comment: Finally, I found something. Check the answer, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `layer.setRadius()` method in `L.Draw.Event.CREATED` event. I think you need a script as follows.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    var type = e.layerType;

    var title = prompt("Please provide the name", "default");
    var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefined");

    var PopupOptions = { 'maxWidth': '400', 'className': 'PopupDrawMarker' };

    if (type === 'marker' || type === 'circlemarker') {
        e.layer.options.color = '#170022'

        var jobnumber = prompt("Please provide the number of orders", 1)
        var MarkerPopup = '<b>Your survey: </b> ' + value

        layer.bindPopup(MarkerPopup, PopupOptions).on('click', function (e) {
        });
        layer.bindTooltip('<b></b>' + title, {
            permanent: false,
            direction: 'center',
            offset: [0, -20],
            className: 'draw-label',
            noWrap: true
        });
        /////////////////////////////////////////  
        if (type === 'circlemarker')           //
            layer.setRadius(jobnumber * 10);   //  
        /////////////////////////////////////////
    } else {

        layer.bindPopup('<b>Name: </b>' + title + '<br> <b>Value: </b>' + value)
        layer.bindTooltip('<b></b>' + title, {
            permanent: false,
            direction: 'center',
            offset: [0, 1],
            className: 'draw-label',
            noWrap: true
        })
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

});
```

[image]

Make sure you added this to `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>


<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/Leaflet.Draw.Event.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/leaflet.draw.css">

<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/Toolbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/Tooltip.js"></script>

<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/GeometryUtil.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/LatLngUtil.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/LineUtil.Intersect.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/Polygon.Intersect.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/Polyline.Intersect.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/ext/TouchEvents.js"></script>

<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/DrawToolbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Feature.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.SimpleShape.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Marker.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Circle.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.CircleMarker.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polygon.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Rectangle.js"></script>


<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/EditToolbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Edit.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Delete.js"></script>

<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/Control.Draw.js"></script>

<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.Poly.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.SimpleShape.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.Rectangle.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.Marker.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.CircleMarker.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/src/edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope that your answer was bountied as I was away from my PC for several days.

Comment: You owe me +50. :) Just kidding.